# How to fix System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have two Data Tables and want to combine them to form one Data Table based on their individual ID's.

The column columnName should get summed up if the ID is duplicated across the two initial Data Tables.

When I run my code I get this error

> How to fix System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

```
DataTable SubData = dsResult.Tables[0];

var query = SubData.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => new
{
    ProductID = row.Field<Int64>("ProductID"),
    PrdCode = row.Field<string>("PrdCode")
}).Select(grp =>
{
    dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
    var dict = result as IDictionary<string, object>;
    result.ProductID = grp.Key.ProductID;
    result.PrdCode = grp.Key.PrdCode;

    foreach (DataRow row in grp)
    {
       foreach (DataColumn column in SubData.Columns)
       {
          string columnName = column.ColumnName;

          if (columnName.Equals("ProductID") || columnName.Equals("PrdCode"))
          {
              continue;
          }

          if (!dict.Keys.Contains(columnName))
          {
              dict[columnName] = row[columnName];
          }
          else
          {
             if (row[columnName] is System.DBNull)
             {
                continue;
             }

             if (dict[columnName] is System.DBNull)
             {
                 dict[columnName] = row[columnName];
                 continue;
             }

             dict[columnName] = (Int64)dict[columnName] + (Int64)row[columnName];
          }
      }
  }

  return result;
});

foreach (var item in query)
{
    dtGraph.Rows.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Post the full description of the exception, please.

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Getting error for  dict[columnName] = (Int64)dict[columnName] + (Int64)row[columnName];

Comment: Code indentation a mess, tidied up code in line with StyleCop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify the data in 'dict'. There must be a value which you can't convert to 'int'